# fatal error: arm_acle.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, arm, g++, cross-compiling, crc32

I'm trying to cross-compile a c++ application to ARM 64 bits using the following command, on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-4.8  -Wall -std=c++0x -O0 -march=armv8-a+crc -c mySRCs.c -o myOBJs.o
```

I want to use the crc32 instruction like:

```
crc = __crc32w(crc, value);
```

and I included in the code:

```
#include <arm_acle.h>
```

but the header is not being found during the compilation, which shows:

```
fatal error: arm_acle.h: No such file or directory

#include <arm_acle.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

If I don't include the header explicitly, the following error appears:

```
error: ‘__crc32w’ was not declared in this scope
  crc = __crc32w(crc, val);
```

A sample of the code:

```
#include <arm_acle.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>

int main(){

        uint32_t val = 56;

        uint32_t crc = 0;

        crc = __crc32w(crc, val);

        printf("Result: %u\n",crc);

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Where did you learn about that header and function? Is the header file anywhere on your system (like if you do e.g. `locate arm_acle.h` or `find /usr -name 'arm_acle.h'` do you get any hits)?

Comment: You still need to provide the path to that header file to the compiler (-I option)

Answer (score 3):

GCC 4.8 is a 4 year old compiler (released [March 2013](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html)), and was the [first GCC release](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) providing early support for the AArch64 execution state of ARMv8.

Support for the CRC instrinsics, such as `__crc32w(crc, value);` exposed through `<arm_acle.h>` were added to GCC mainline on [11th June 2014](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=211440), and included in the GCC 5.1 release.

You'll need a GCC 5.1 or later compiler if you want access to the `<arm_acle.h>` system header.